# Combinatorics and symmetry in matrices under row and column swaps

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices, permutations, symmetry

Suppose we have a $m\times n$ matrix and a sequence of numbers with which to fill the matrix, $\{c_1,c_2 \dots c_k \}$. I like to think of the numbers as colors, hence the notation. How many unique configurations can we produce if we are given that matrices are equivalent when one matrix can be transformed to another via one or more row or column swaps?

As a concrete example consider the case for a $2\times 2$ matrix with the list of numbers $\{ 1, 3\}$. Notice that the numbers must sum to the product of the dimensions of the matrix. Let us say $c_1$ is denoted by $1$ and $c_2$ by $0$. Then we need to fill the matrix with one $1$ and three $0's$

There are four possible configurations:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
$$

It is clear that all four of these matrices are equivalent, since any one can be transformed to another via one or more row or column swaps. Hence for the problem of a $2\times 2$ matrix with the list of numbers $\{ 1, 3\}$, there is **ONE** unique configuration we can produce.

As another example consider the case of $2\times 2$ with the list of numbers $\{ 2, 2\}$, again we denote $c_1$ by $1$ and $c_2$ by $0$.

There are six configurations:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
$$

Now, the first can be transformed to the second by $R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2$. The third can be transformed to the fourth via $C_1 \leftrightarrow C_2$ and the fifth can become the sixth either via $R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2$ or $C_1 \leftrightarrow C_2$. What we are left with are **THREE** unique configurations under row and column swaps.

I hope the reader will get the idea of how the problem is presented, but I will be happy to clarify if needed.

I know that for a given $m$, $n$ and $\{ c_1, c_2 \dots, c_k \}$ the total number of possible configurations is:

$$\frac{(m \cdot n)!}{c_1!\cdot c_2! \cdot \dots  c_k!}$$

I am however unable to incorporate the the swapping of rows and columns. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In principle you can approach this problem via the Pólya-Redfield enumeration technique, but you may not get such a nice answer.

Comment: Swop means swap?

Comment: Is there a reason you use $n$ both for the number of colors and the width of the matrix? Can these be different numbers?

Comment: The $n's$ can be different and swop means swap yes.

Comment: A related problem is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373094.

Comment: Here is a natural question related to this: just consider the case of 0's and 1's ($k=2$) and let $x_i$ be the number of such $m\times n$ matrices (up to permutation of rows & columns)  with $i$ 1's. Then is the sequence $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{mn}$ unimodal? It seems very likely to be the case.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I think your unimodality question is a special case of Theorem 5.8 or Corollary 7.16 of my book *Algebraic Combinatorics*, second ed. An even stronger result is Exercise 7.75(c) of EC2 (using the nonnegativity of $a_\lambda$ in equation (7.120)).

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate on the use of Pólya enumeration for this problem.

Let $G\simeq S_m \times S_n$ act on $X=\{x_{i,j}\colon 1\leq i \leq m, 1\leq j \leq n\}$ via $(\sigma,\pi)\cdot x_{i,j} = x_{\sigma(i),\pi(j)}$, and via this action view $G\subseteq S_{mn}$. For $g\in G$ let $c_i(g)$ be the number of $i$-cycles of $g$ (in this embedding into $S_{mn}$), and form the corresponding cycle index
$$ Z_{G}(t_1,t_2,\ldots) = \frac{1}{\#G}\sum_{g\in G} t_1^{c_1(g)}t_2^{c_2(g)}\cdots.$$
Then by the [Pólya-Redfield enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem), the number of $m \times n$ matrices, with $\alpha_1$ $1$'s, $\alpha_2$ $2$'s, ..., $\alpha_k$ $k$'S considered up to permutation of rows and columns, is
$$ [y_1^{\alpha_1}y_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots y_k^{\alpha_k}] Z_{G}(y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_k,y_1^2+y_2^2+\cdots+y_k^2,y_1^3+y_2^3+\cdots+y_k^3,\ldots).$$
(Here $[\mathbf{y}^{\alpha}]$ denotes coefficient extraction, and I switched from your notation of $\{c_1,\ldots,c_k\}$ to $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k\}$ to not get confused with the common notation in the definition of the cycle index.)

For example, consider the case $m=n=2$. Then
$$G= \{(x_{11})(x_{12})(x_{21})(x_{22}),(x_{11},x_{21})(x_{12}x_{22}),(x_{11},x_{12})(x_{21}x_{22}),(x_{11},x_{22})(x_{12}x_{21}) \}$$
so
$$ Z_{G}(t_1,t_2,\ldots) = \frac{1}{4}\left( t_1^4 + 3\cdot t_2^2 \right).$$
Thus, the number of $2\times 2$ matrices with $2$ 0's and $2$ 1's, up to permutation of rows and columns, is
$$ [y_0^2y_1^2]Z_{G}(y_0+y_1,y_0^2+y_1^2,\ldots) = [y_0^2y_1^2] \frac{1}{4}( (y_0+y_1)^4 + 3(y_0^2+y_1^2)^2) \\ = [y_0^2y_1^2](y_0^4 + y_0^3y_1 + 3y_0^2y_1^2 + y_0y_1^3+y_1^4)=3,$$
as you demonstrated above.

So to address the case of general $m$ and $n$, we need to understand $Z_G$ precisely. In other words, for a pair $\sigma \in S_m$ and $\pi \in S_n$, we need to understand the cycle structure of the corresponding element $g=(\sigma,\pi)\in G \subseteq S_{mn}$.

Note that in this last example we saw that if $\sigma$ is a $2$-cycle and $\pi$ is a $2$-cycle, then $g=(\sigma,\pi)$ will consist of $2$ $2$-cycles. But for instance if $\sigma$ is a $2$-cycle and $\pi$ is a $3$-cycle, then $g=(\sigma,\pi)$ will be one $6$-cycle. In general, if $\sigma$ is an $m$-cycle and $\pi$ is a $n$-cycle, then $g=(\sigma,\pi)$ will consist of $\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)$ $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$-cycles. And then of course we can figure out the cycle structure of $g=(\sigma,\pi)$ for arbitrary $\sigma$ and $\pi$ by comparing pairwise the cycles of $\sigma$ and $\pi$.

Recall that for a partition $\lambda=(1^{m_1},2^{m_2},\cdots) \vdash n$, the number of permutations in $S_n$ of cycle type $\lambda$ is $z_{\lambda} = \frac{n!}{1^{m_1}m_1!2^{m_2}m_2!\cdots}$. Thus, the rule from the previous paragraph in principle allows you to easily compute $Z_G$ for any fixed $m,n$; but it introduces some nontrivial arithmetic which makes me doubt there will be any truly simple formula one can write down.

**EDIT**: Okay, so from the above we can write in general that
$$ Z_G(t_1,t_2,\ldots) =\sum_{\substack{\lambda=(1^{m_1},2^{m_2},\cdots)\vdash m, \\ \mu=(1^{m'_1},2^{m'_2},\cdots)\vdash n}} \frac{\prod_{i,j\geq 1}t_{\mathrm{lcm}(i,j)}^{\mathrm{gcd}(i,j) \cdot m_i \cdot m'_j}}{1^{m_1} m_1! 2^{m_2} m_2!\cdots 1^{m'_1} m'_1! 2^{m'_2} m'_2! \cdots} .$$
For any fixed $m$, $n$ this formula should be able to be quickly evaluated with a computer.

**EDIT 2**: Here is some [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) code for this problem:

```
m=3
n=3
k=2
R = PolynomialRing(QQ, ['t%s'%i for i in range(1,m*n+1)])
S = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'y', k)
z = 0
for p in Partitions(m):
    for q in Partitions(n):
        g=1
        for i in range(1,len(p.to_exp())+1):
            for j in range(1,len(q.to_exp())+1):
               g = g * R.gens()[lcm(i,j)-1]^(gcd(i,j)*p.to_exp()[i-1]*q.to_exp()[j-1])
        for i in range(1,len(p.to_exp())+1):
            g = g * 1/(factorial(p.to_exp()[i-1])*i^(p.to_exp()[i-1]))
        for j in range(1,len(q.to_exp())+1):
            g = g * 1/(factorial(q.to_exp()[j-1])*j^(q.to_exp()[j-1]))
        z = z + g
print("Cycle index: " + str(z))
f = z.subs({R.gens()[i-1]:sum([S.gens()[j]^i for j in range(k)]) for i in range(1,m*n+1)})
print("Colorings generating function: " + str(f))
```

which produces the output

```
Cycle index: 1/36*t1^9 + 1/6*t1^3*t2^3 + 1/4*t1*t2^4 + 2/9*t3^3 + 1/3*t3*t6
Colorings generating function: y0^9 + y0^8*y1 + 3*y0^7*y1^2 + 6*y0^6*y1^3 + 7*y0^5*y1^4 + 7*y0^4*y1^5 + 6*y0^3*y1^6 + 3*y0^2*y1^7 + y0*y1^8 + y1^9
```

This tells us, for example, that there are 7 $3\times 3$ matrices of 5 $0$'s and 4 $1$'s up to permutation of rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. A lot of this goes over my head, but I will study up on the  Pólya-Redfield enumeration theorem.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do the $k_1, k_2, k_3, \dots$ indices in  your second post (answer) correspond to the $\{c_1, \cdots, c_k \}$ colors of your first post?

Comment: @InesInstitoris: yes sorry I switched that notation because $c_i$ is so commonly used in the definition of the cycle index; I now made it $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ to maybe be a little clearer.

Comment: After making the substitutions $t_i \mapsto p_i$ where $p_i = y_1^i + \cdots + y_k^i$ is the $i$-th power-symmetric polynomial, you obtain a new symmetric polynomial $Z_G(p_1, \dots, p_{mn})$. If I may ask, what's the expansion of $Z_G(p_1, \dots, p_{mn})$ in terms of Schur polynomials?

Comment: @InesInstitoris: Are you asking about this in the general context of Polya theory, or for this particular problem?

Comment: At any rate, see Stanley, EC2, Section 7.24. It is basically the character of the permutation representation of the symmetric group on the set of colors acting on the set of colorings.

Comment: Just for simplicity of notation, note that $\frac{ij}{\mathrm{lcm}(i,j)}=\mathrm{gcd}(i,j)$.